# Forçar redirecionamento de https para http de página específica

Tags: php, http, https, redirect

Tenho um site que está em `https`, porém há uma página específica que puxa informações de outro site que não está em `https`, o que impede a página em questão de carregar corretamente o conteúdo, pois o navegador fica bloqueando o carregamento devido ao fato de a página de origem do conteúdo não estar em `https`, diante disso preciso encontrar uma forma em `PHP` de forçar o redirecionamento de `https` para `http` **apenas** na página **www.domínio.com.br/clipping** e manter as demais páginas do site como `https`.

No momento meu código está assim, porém não está funcionando, sempre dá erro de redirecionamento incorreto.

```
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
   $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   if ($url == "/clipping"){
      $link = "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. $url;
      header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
      header("Location: $link");
      exit;
   }
}
```